How do I make a QLineEdit Action change color when hovered?
I am new to PyQt and I am creating some custom QLineEdit Widgets that I add some SVG Actions to. I want to make them change color when the user hovers over them to signify that they are clickable. If possible I would also like to include the cursor changing.
Here is an example of one of my fields:
class ModernPasswordField(ModernField):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Password') # ModernField just adds a label and styling to the QLineEdit

        self.entry_field.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)

        copy_icon = QtGui.QIcon('resources/test/copy.svg')
        lock_icon = QtGui.QIcon('resources/test/lock.svg')
        generate_icon = QtGui.QIcon('resources/test/refresh.svg')
        hidden_icon = QtGui.QIcon('resources/used/invisible_eye_white.svg')

        self.entry_field.addAction(lock_icon, QtWidgets.QLineEdit.LeadingPosition) # Not clickable
        copy_action = self.entry_field.addAction(copy_icon, QtWidgets.QLineEdit.TrailingPosition)
        hidden_action = self.entry_field.addAction(hidden_icon, QtWidgets.QLineEdit.TrailingPosition)
        generate_action = self.entry_field.addAction(generate_icon, QtWidgets.QLineEdit.TrailingPosition)

I tried looking at the documentation, but I haven't seen any styling options for changing the QIcon or color when hovered. I looked at some solutions where I override some events, but that might be overkill and I am looking to see if there is a better solution to this problem.

python - How to Catch Hover and Mouse Leave Signal In PyQt5 - Stack Overflow

using styles: PyQt5 - Changing background color of Label when hover - GeeksforGeeks

@furas How do I apply that to the actions?

The actions added to QLineEdit are internally managed as QToolButtons (similarly to QToolBar).
One possibility is then to create a QGraphicsOpacityEffect for those buttons as soon as they've been created, and install an event filter on them in order to check for Enter and Leave events.
For example:
class HoverLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def childEvent(self, event):
        super().childEvent(event)
        if event.type() == event.ChildPolished:
            widget = event.child()
            if isinstance(widget, QToolButton):
                widget.installEventFilter(self)
                effect = QGraphicsOpacityEffect(widget)
                effect.setOpacity(.5)
                widget.setGraphicsEffect(effect)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if isinstance(obj, QToolButton):
            if event.type() == event.Enter:
                obj.graphicsEffect().setEnabled(False)
            elif event.type() == event.Leave:
                obj.graphicsEffect().setEnabled(True)
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

